# RPM.spec does not unset of an env

Tags: environment-variables, rpm, uninstallation, unset, relocation

I am trying to do "unset" of an env variable from my  rpm.spec file. which is not happening

Note that i am not exporting that env inside my rpm.spec.(i will do an export my self in cmd line)

$export user=akshatha

$export group=akshatha1

---

rpm.spec:

%postun

unset user

unset group

---

uninstalling the package:

$rpm -e (rpm_package)

check whether the value is unset or not(which is not unset):

$ echo $user

akshatha

$echo $group

akshatha1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up what an rpm package is and what it can do.

Environment variables are set within a (bash, shell,...) Session. When you set variables and you start a new session, these variables are gone.

Rpm packages are supposed to install files at certain locations, to make permanent, system wide changes (like installing software). An rpm package, nor the installation of an rpm package is linked to your bash session (the installation will run in a separate session by the way).

You should not try to influence your environment variables with your rpm.

In the very unlikely case that you do need to export some kind of environment variable, then you should try to make it system wide available, for example declaring it in /etc/bashrc or something similar.